# Negating an iff statement: find definition of *not secret* given definition of *secret*

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> A set $A$ is a secret iff $\forall x \in A$ there $\exists y \in A$ such that $3 \div|x - y|$. Or else, $A$ is not a secret.

What is the statement:

> A set $A$ is *not secret* iff ________

I am not sure how to use the negation here. Is it a negation or not? Would I do the negation of the "if" part only?

Comment: You simply have a different statement. That is "If $A$ is not a secret then *stuff*, and if *stuff* then $A$ is not a secret."

Comment: In this case you can just negate both sides. $(x\Leftrightarrow y)\Leftrightarrow(\neg x\Leftrightarrow \neg y)$

Comment: By the way, the interpretation of $3 \div|x - y|$ as a statement with a truth value seems unusual to me. If the meaning is that $\lvert x - y\rvert$ is divisible by $3$, I would have expected something like $3\mid(\lvert x - y\rvert)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $p \iff q$ and $\lnot p \iff \lnot q$ are logically equivalent, the definition
$$
A \text{ is secret} \iff \varphi 
$$
is logically equivalent to
$$
A \text{ is not secret} \iff \lnot \varphi.
$$
So find what $\varphi$ is, then find $\lnot \varphi$, then write the above formula.

**Warning:** this is NOT the same as negating an iff statement. The negation of $p \iff q$ is $p \text{ xor } q$, NOT $\lnot p \iff \lnot q$.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of
$$\tag1\forall x\in A,\exists y\in A,3\div |x-y| $$
is 
$$\tag2\exists x\in A,\forall  y\in A,\neg(3\div |x-y|) $$
We are given that $A$ is a secret iff $(1)$. Hence $A$ is not a secret iff $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks. If I use De Morgan's law however, I get that the negation of the bi-conditional statement (A <->B) to be $A \and \not B) \or (B \and \not A)$

Comment: Do you want the negation $\neg(A\leftrightarrow B)$? Yo question looked more like yo wanted to know the $x$ in $(\neg A)\leftrightarrow x$, where $A\leftrightarrow B$ is known.

Answer (score 0):

The negation of your statement is

if set $\mathbf A$ is not a secret $\Rightarrow$ there is no $y \in \mathbf A$ such that $3 \div \lvert x-y \rvert \forall x \in \mathbf A $ or  set $\mathbf A$ is not a secret if  $ \exists x \in \mathbf A$ such that $3 \div \lvert x-y \rvert $ is not true